# Currency Format for CSV File

Tags: c#, csv, currency

I'm formatting a currency to local standard e.g.

Format 20000 to R 20 000,00 using the standard C# double.ToString()

```
String amount = order.Amount.ToString( "C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( "en-ZA" ) );
```

This works pretty well until the data is exported into a CSV file which produces some funny characters like this one: R 20Â 000,00. If I open the same cvs file in a plain text file all looks good.

Anyone know how I can get rid of that ugly looking A?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

Here's how the csv file gets created:

```
return File( new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes( csv ), "text/csv", "Order_Report.csv" );
```

I'm writing my app using ASP.NET MVC and Opening it in Excel just by opening a regular CSV file.

Comment: Try to change the encoding format of your filestream writer to UTF-8 if it isn't

Comment: Like @Kabulan0lak said, your problem is probably in how you persist to csv, or how it is read afterwards. Change to UTF-8 for both writing and reading, or post the relevant code here for someone else to take a look

Comment: I can't seem to edit this post but here's how the csv file gets created:
return File( new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes( csv ), "text/csv", "Order_Report.csv" ); I'm writing my app using ASP.NET MVC and Opening it in Excel just by opening a regular CSV file.

Comment: Thank you though no one wants to help out :(